# how can I callout a public function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a function that checks if internet is connected or not. 
here is the code:

```
 public func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool
{
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
 isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```

and I wanna check internet connectivity in another View Controller too. 
here is my attempt :

```
 let internetConnectivity = isInternetAvailable()
    if internetConnectivity == true {
   //do Stuff
    }
```

but I get the following error :

> Use of unresolved identifier 'isInternetAvailable'

so how can I fix this ?

Comment: I really wish the person who downvotes my post told me where I'm going wrong :|

Comment: What class is the `isInternetAvailable` function in?

Comment: @rmaddy it's in Login ViewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a `func` declared in a class, then you need an instance of that class in order to call the function.  So, you can't just call `isInternetAvailable()` without having an object to call it on, like `myVC.isInternetAvailable()`

In your specific case, there is no reason for that function to be declared inside a VC because it has nothing to do with that ViewController and doesn't need any data from it (or any privileged access).

The easiest thing to do is to make it a global func (top level, probably in a different file).

Another common thing to do is to wrap it in a singleton service object (which you can look up -- it's the kind of thing `UserDefaults` does)

Comment: This seems like a reasonable tutorial on singletons: https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift/